# How to convert SSL certificate to PFX if the certificate does not allow private key export

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have an SSL certificate that I need to convert to PFX file.

I have the following info

1. `.crt` file
2. `.pem` file
3. `.p7b` file
4. The CSR and the Private key.

I tried to follow the direction listed [here](https://thesecmaster.com/step-by-step-procedure-to-convert-a-cer-certificate-to-pfx-without-the-private-key/) which worked until step `15. Export the Private Key`.

In my case, the `.PFX` option is grayed out. From a research, this is grayed out because the certificate does not allow exporting the private key.

Since I have the private key, how can I export the certificate to `.PFX` file?
[image]

I also tried to convert it using [this online tool](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) and that did not work.

> There was a problem converting that certificate. It may be corrupt or it may be in a different format than the one you selected. You can try using a different format or running the OpenSSL commands on your own machine. The private key also may not match the certificate that you uploaded. Go back

Comment: There's no legitimate way.  Like "how do I get access to a computer without a valid login?" you're now in the realm of "you can't" aka "hacking is required".

Comment: Can you request a replacement certificate?  If so, request one where the private key can be exported.

Comment: @garethTheRed isn't a security risk to generate a certificate with exportable key?

Comment: PFX (PKCS#12) files are normally used where a private key is required.  I assume that the reason you're asking this question is because you need the certificate and key exported for use on a specific application.  If that's the case, then you have no option other than to export the private key.  Also remember that this exportable private key concept is a Microsoft-ism.  It's not available in Java, Linux etc.  There are ways to generate a PKCS#12 file without the private key, but it's just a certificate in that case, and is probably not what you need.